# I want to put a text and image in imageview

Tags: android, imageview

i used bitmap to crop image. now I could draw text on the image, but i want it below the image of same imageview. I have seen some using the textview below the image, but my requirement is to put text and image in single imageview.

**my main class:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

static ImageView imageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.images_1);        
    imageView.setImageBitmap(getCircleBitmap(bitmap));

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


public static Bitmap getCircleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

    //crop to circle 
    Bitmap output;
    //check if its a rectangular image
    if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
        output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    } else {
        output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getWidth(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    }
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    float r = 0;

    if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
        r = bitmap.getHeight() / 2;
    } else {
        r = bitmap.getWidth() / 2;
    }

    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);

    canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    int x = (bitmap.getWidth() - bounds.width())/2;
    int y = (bitmap.getHeight() + bounds.height())/2; 

    canvas.drawText("hii",x,y, paint);

    return output;
}
```

**in my xml file:**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A safe way is to create your image and add it's text under it (in photoshop for example) and then save it as png and use it. it won't use much space and you can have your own font style etc.
however the previous answers are good and you can use them as well

Answer (score 0):

you can try like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Since a RealativeLayout stacks its children, defining the TextView after ImageView puts it 'over' the ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

Just one suggestion.
Rather adding text to image view add image to text view.
If you can go through few following attributes of textview,i guess you might find some way out.

```
        android:drawableTop=""
        android:drawableBottom=""
        android:drawableLeft=""
        android:drawableRight=""
        android:drawableStart=""
        android:drawableEnd=""
        android:drawablePadding=""
```

Comment: Like an icon on our desktop, which contains image and text under that. same thing iam trying for.

Comment: TRY android:drawableTop="" IN TEXTVIEW

Comment: This will work to put text below an imageview in relative layout,but not below the cropped image into circular form. Try to execute my code above, to get clear clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Take one TextView in XML with Image View and access both in java file and set it like that

```
TextView.setText(yourtext);
imageview.setImageBitmap(yourbitmapobject);
```